# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar un problema de gdal en R y en Ubuntu?

Tags: r, ubuntu, rstudio, librería, error404

Estoy trabajando en Ubuntu con Rstudio para trabajar con imágenes raster y TIFF, y para ello necesito utilizar la siguiente función:

```
mosaic_rasters(gdalfile=all_my_rasts,dst_dataset=paste0(ruta_mosaico, "/", "mosaic.tif"), of="GTiff")
```

Sin embargo, sigo recibiendo el siguiente error repetidamente:

```
Error in gdal_chooseInstallation(hasDrivers = of) : 
  No installations match.
```

Estoy urilizando las siguientes versiones de librerías

```
gdal-config --versiom -> 3.3.2
R --version -> R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15) -- "Shortstop Beagle"
```

He reinstalado todo, he probado casi todo lo que he encontrado en internet, pero no consigo solucionarlo.

He probado cambiando la versión, reinstalando gdal, instalando todo desde cero... pero siempre acabo con el mismo problema.

Comment: ¿Qué te retorna esto: `library("gdalUtils");rep(x=TRUE,times=length(getOption("gdalUtils_gdalPath")))`?

Comment: Instalaste GDAL y GEOS? Te recomiendo cambiarte a {terra} o {stars}, son librerías más nuevas y que realizarán el mosaico más rápido